Logic Puzzle with (potentially?) interesting Graph Theory relevance
I've been given a logic puzzle that is presented as follows:
\begin{array} {|r|r|}\hline 1 & 3 & \text{END} & 3/2 & 2 \\ \hline 1 & 2/1 & 1 & 5 & 3 \\ \hline 2/1 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 2 \\ \hline 1 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 1 \\ \hline 3 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 2/1 \\ \hline 1 & 2 & 2 & 2/1 & 1 \\ \hline 3 & 3 & S/2 & 1 & 5 \\ \hline  \end{array}
We have to start at the square marked $S$. For each move, we look at the number in the cell currently occupied and move that number of squares in any direction (e.g. the first move, we move $2$ squares north, $2$ squares east or $2$ squares west). Looping around the grid edges is not allowed. The goal is to reach the square marked $\text{END}$ having visited every single square on the grid exactly once (with a few exceptions).
For cells (other than the start) with a $/$, we have to visit the cell exactly twice - the first visit takes the first value in the square, and the second visit takes the second value.
Being someone with limited ability with brute-force/guesswork, I wanted to try and solve this puzzle using a more algorithmic approach. I modelled the grid as a graph, with a vertex representing each square. A directed edge is added between squares $i$ and $j$ if you can get from square $i$ to square $j$ in $1$ move.
For the 'double' squares, I modelled them as having two vertices, the first with a value of $i$, and the second with a value of $i-1$ (for whatever $i$ is for that square). That way, the problem in essence becomes finding a Hamiltonian path from $S$ to $\text{END}$, with extra constraints.
My issue is that when I try and use an online solver to generate such a Hamiltonian path, it generates paths where the lower value of the 'double' square is used before the higher value. Is there a good way to modify the graph such that it forces the path to go to the higher value vertex first?
I should clarify that I cannot code to save my life - this question is a purely graph theoretical question and not a question of 'can I just code the graph to change halfway through the algorithm'. I'm using a basic Hamiltonian path finder that I found on the internet that just does (I assume) a breadth first search and prints the first Hamiltonian path it finds.

Have you considered reversing the path? In general there seem to be fewer ways to get to a cell than to leave it. This may also work well with the solver you found, if it always takes the smaller value first.

Unfortunately it doesn't always take the smaller value, it kind of just goes by convenience (whichever it finds a solution for first). I can definitely try reversing everything and see what happens though :3

I tried something using multiple copies of the graph while still searching for an Hamiltonian graph. I did not found a satisfactory solution, though I think one might do it. However such approach seems difficult to adapt when you have several occurences of "double nodes"

I had a similar idea, though I realised that trying to find a Hamiltonian path with multiple copies of the graph would also result in every square being hit multiple times.
It's also very inefficient for multiple double nodes as you noted. (something like 2^n copies of the grid for n double nodes)

Addendum added to respond to the comment of Kiran Shiatis


"I should clarify that I cannot code to save my life ..."

As a retired professional programmer, I know as much about graph theory as a giraffe does.  To clarify, although I can make an educated guess, I do not know what a Hamiltonian path is.
However, taking your posted question at face value, you seem to have provided enough information for me to express an opinion.
The fact that a corresponding online solver exists in the first place suggests to me that (in general) there is no elegant way of attacking reasonably complicated Hamiltonian paths, absent computer assistance.
In effect, I would further surmise that the problem analogizes to a sudoku problem or a chess mate in $~n~$ problem, both of which have computer directed solvers.  That is, for both such problems, there is no elegant means of attack.
That is, in both such problems, absent computer assistance, you simply learn fundamental concepts,  and then try to creatively apply them.  So, I am speculating that attacking a Hamiltonian path is no different.
Assuming that my surmise is true, when an additional constraint is added to a reasonably complicated Hamiltonian path, it seems very plausible to me to expect that the revised problem also excludes any elegant attack, absent computer assistance.
Therefore, if you are unable to dissect and modify the pseudocode inherent in an online solver, and then create your own customized solver, I would surmise that it is game over.

$\underline{\text{Addendum}}$
Responding to the comment of Kiran Shiatis:

The issue is not with the code or the method of coding... 
...My question was not to amend code in any way, but rather to amend the graph into something that forces the Hamiltonian path solver to do the right thing.

This is a very creative approach that never occurred to me.
In fact, I completely agree with you that because of your intended approach, this is no longer a programming issue.  Instead, this is in fact an issue of math analysis.

For cells (other than the start) with a /
, we have to visit the cell exactly twice - the first visit takes the first value in the square, and the second visit takes the second value.

My instinct, which could easily be mistaken, is that your approach is not feasible.
That is, I don't see how you can design a graph of connected vertices, that dynamically changes some of the connections after a cell is visited.
Therefore, it seems as if you need to split each "/ cell" into two cells, and then specify the order that the two cells are visited.
Analytically, I don't see how this constraint can be expressed by constructing a new graph of connected vertices, that is designed to bypass the cell-ordering constraint.
That is, even ignoring the issue of splitting the "/ cell", it seems that a Hamiltonian path, by its very nature, imposes no constraint on the order that cells are visited.
So, you would apparently be left with the idea of creating a new graph of connected vertices such that it is (in effect) impossible to encounter "split-cell-1b" without first encountering "split-cell-1a".
However, as you describe the problem, "split-cell-1b", would not connect to "split-cell-1a", but would in fact connect to other cells.  So, how could any graph of connected vertices be designed to prevent "split-cell-1b" from being encountered before "split-cell-1a"?

The issue is not with the code or the method of coding. It is with the problem construction itself.
I maybe should have been clearer with my problem - a Hamiltonian path is just the fancy name for a path that hits every vertex in your graph exactly once.
With the graph construction I came up with as a start, I encountered the problem described in the question, where the lower value was used in the path before the higher value. My question was not to amend code in any way, but rather to amend the graph into something that forces the Hamiltonian path solver to do the right thing.

If it is at all helpful, here is the website I used with the Hamiltonian path calculator: https://graphonline.ru/en/?graph=HamiltonianGraph
I should reinforce that this is NOT a coding question. This is a question on whether it is possible to amend the graph construction itself.

Perhaps a useful rephrase of the question is:
'Given this solver that can find a Hamiltonian Path for a graph, can I construct a graph from the puzzle proposed that will guarantee that the solution generated is valid in the context of the puzzle.'

@KiranShiatis See the Addendum that I have just added to the end of my answer.
